# Does Spring DI cause memory problems?

Tags: spring, memory, dependency-injection

Spring DI preinstantiates all of the objects configured in the xml file. I am concerned that all the objects are pre-created and live a long time in the heap memory. Does Spring DI create memory issues? If not, how it is problem solved in Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects representing Spring beans usually live for the duration of the application context which again usually lives for the entire application's life time.

Therefore, Spring beans should not become to heavy weight by for example keeping references to all objects that are ever passed to Spring beans. This is however the responsibility of the application developer using Spring. Since you usually enumerate all Spring beans, usually, the Spring beans by themselfs should not occupy too much memory in the heap. In general, however, you are right. Badly written beans can cause memory leaks in Java applications but any badly written code can.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about Spring that makes your code any more likely for memory leaks or increased memory consumption.

Spring configuration is just a declarative way of saying something like this:

```
MyDependency dep = new MyDependency();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.setDependency(dep);
```

which you would do yourself anyway.

Spring keeps references to singleton-scoped beans, which will be garbage collected when the application context is. But if you have enough of these to cause a problem, you probably have bigger issues. Meanwhile, Spring does not keep references to prototype beans it manages.

Projects worldwide have been using Spring extensively for nearly a decade. Don't you think any memory issues would've been known--and solved--by now?

Comment: Spring is more like having a `static` variable. The difference to Spring is that `MyClass` would usually never garbage collected why this is a reasonable assumption for *normal* classes.